# warning during compilation of lwip example lib

Tags: lwip

i am compiling the example in
/ports/unix/lib
from
http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/lwip/lwip-contrib.git
as instructed in the README file and get a compilation warning

```
../../../../lwip/src/api/sockets.c:746: error: logical ‘||’ with non-zero constant will always evaluate as true
```

the error is related to this define

```
#define SOCK_ADDR_TYPE_MATCH_OR_UNSPEC(name, sock) (((name)->sa_family == AF_UNSPEC) || \
                                                SOCK_ADDR_TYPE_MATCH(name, sock))

#define SOCK_ADDR_TYPE_MATCH(name, sock) 1
```

i know the problem with it but cannot understand if it was intended or not

should i ignore it, or am i doing something wrong?

it is also does not create the file liblwip4unixlib.so
that it should create when compilation does complete

Comment: It will help if you add some code

Comment: the compilation command is
make clean all

Comment: I meant, add the code that is causing the compilation error

Comment: the code that causes the error is an or with a define at one end, the define is defined as 1

Comment: Then the error says exactly what you have, the logical Or will always be true because "1" evaluates to "true" which means that the condition is redundant (as it is always true)

Comment: the code is from the lwip project, i have not changed it
i have tried to compile it "as is" with their instructions

Comment: You're probably compiling with -Werror as opposed to lwip. Change the compilation flags so that this error remains just a warning and it will compile